# How to close popup.html for my google extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I visibly hide my popup.html whenever I click a button on that popup. I want to keep my scripts running but minimize the popup off the page. The reason i'm doing this is because i'm making an eye dropper extension that can get the color under your cursor and perhaps that color is being blocked by the popup hence why I want to get hide it when I'm looking for a color. Once I've picked my color the popup reappears.

Comment: You'll have to resize it. The minimum size is 16x16. For example via CSS: html \* {display: none  !important}

Comment: Could you also use CSS positioning to move it off the screen or z-index to send it backward?

Comment: @wOxxOm so i tried doing 
document.querySelector('*').style.setProperty('display', 'none', 'important');
but that doesn't work inside of my event listener that listens for a button click. Although it does work outside of it

Comment: @RyanO'D no the popup doesn't like being moved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to resize the popup e.g. by hiding everything inside. The minimum size is still 16x16.

popup.js should call `start()` inside some event listener:

```js
function start() {
  Object.assign(document.documentElement, {
    className: 'hidden',
    title: 'Click to cancel',
    onclick: stop,
  });
}
function stop() {
  Object.assign(document.documentElement, {
    className: '',
    title: '',
    onclick: null,
  });
}
```

popup.css:

```css
html.hidden * {
  display: none !important
}

html.hidden::after {
  content: 'x';
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Well like before, chrome has security measures in place so calling start() inside my event listener doesn't work, however, calling start outside of my event listener works. This was the same problem as before as the styling didn't work outside of the event listener, security blocking it.

Comment: i do have an event listener not an onclick
https://github.com/rreconix/Chrome-Extension
line 32 in popup.js is my event listener

Comment: The link should work now. I guess my problem is now, that when I do '
document.querySelector('*').style.setProperty('display', 'none', 'important');'
inside my event listener it only hides the elements inside the popup, not the window itself

Comment: Forget about the security measures, im doing document.querySelector('*') to apply the css you showed me to all my elements. Now my issue is my popup's elements are gone (which is good) but the actual popup is still the same size and still very visibile (i want to make that popup be the minimum of 16x16 pixels)

Comment: Yes that works but I can still see the elements when i use my color tool it still shows the element is there: https://gyazo.com/5b0f3a752fde863e475642321ec47df5

Comment: Looks like a bug in eye picker. Try calling it inside setTimeout callback.